# Is there a way to list all endpoints of a Micronaut app

Tags: micronaut

A micronaut app works for me locally, but not in another environment. I get a Micronaut error (not network error) saying the URL i'm trying to access is not defined.

```
{"message":"Not Found","_links":{"self":{"href":"/myApp/debug/loadVins","templated":false}},"_embedded":{"errors":[{"message":"Page Not Found"}]}}
```

Is there a way for me to ask Micronaut to list all the URLs/Endpoints it recognizes? (Like the debug mode in Django)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add micronaut-management as dependency (see https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/#management) you can access the /routes endpoint, see https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/#routesEndpoint